# list out of range how can i fix this and app;y the score

Tags: python, list

```
machine_specs = [] 

for spec in ("Name", "Speed in MHz", "Cores", "Cache in kB", "RAM in GB"):
    data_set = []
    data_val = input(f"{spec}: ")
    if spec == "Speed in MHz":
        data_val = float(data_val)
    elif spec != "Name":
        data_val = int(data_val)
    data_set.append(data_val)
machine_specs.append(data_set)

def score_machine(data):
    score = (
        data[1] / 3 * 25 
      + data[2] / 8 * 25
      + data[3] / 32 * 25
      + data[4] / 8 * 25
    )
    return round(score)

for ms in machine_specs:
    print(f"{ms[0]} scores {score_machine(ms)} out of 100")
```

this is supposed to give a score based on the data you input into the program to give a score out of a hundred based on your specifications their is a problem though

Comment: `data_set` is being recreated every time you start the `for` loop to get input - it will only have the last value you enter and then you put that single value list into `machine_specs`.

Comment: how though it says it is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `data_set = []` in each iteration, So change like this. I think you might also be required to add another loop to get more data into `machine_specs`.

```
machine_specs = []
data_set = []
for spec in ("Name", "Speed in MHz", "Cores", "Cache in kB", "RAM in GB"):
    data_val = input(f"{spec}: ")
    if spec == "Speed in MHz":
        data_val = float(data_val)
    elif spec != "Name":
        data_val = int(data_val)
    data_set.append(data_val)
machine_specs.append(data_set)
```